# vagrant-aws: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I am on Windows 10, and using vagrant-aws (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) to vagrant up and amazon instance, and getting the following error. I have listed my Vagrant file as well.

Also, some people reported this might be caused by the time. I have synced system time on windows 10, but still no luck!

```
$ vagrant up --provider=aws
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...
C:/Users/jacky/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.7.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:98: warning: duplicated key at line 100 ignored: :associate_public_ip
==> default: Warning! The AWS provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
==> default: high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
==> default: will be silently ignored.
==> default: Launching an instance with the following settings...
==> default:  -- Type: m3.medium
==> default:  -- AMI: ami-42116522
==> default:  -- Region: us-west-1
==> default:  -- Keypair: 2016_05_14_keypair
==> default:  -- Block Device Mapping: []
==> default:  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false
==> default:  -- Monitoring: false
==> default:  -- EBS optimized: false
==> default:  -- Source Destination check:
==> default:  -- Assigning a public IP address in a VPC: false
==> default:  -- VPC tenancy specification: default
There was an error talking to AWS. The error message is shown
below:

AuthFailure => AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

Vagrang file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "..."
    aws.secret_access_key = "..."
    aws.session_token = "..."
    aws.keypair_name = "2016_05_14_keypair"

    aws.ami = "ami-42116522"
    aws.region  = "us-west-1"
    #aws.instance_type = "t2.small"
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "C:/2016_05_14_keypair.pem"
  end
end
```

Comment: I had double check by credentials, and all of them are correct.

Comment: How did you generate your session_token?

Comment: aws sts get-session-token --duration-seconds 129600

Comment: Your VagrantFile looks correct wrt to credentials. I am using something similar myself, except I am not using tokens. You might want to use something like `aws cli` to create an instance with your credential, this would definitely rule out a problem with your key / token....

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz, can you show men the complete command?

Comment: I had a strange problem where my .pem file didn't work. use PuTTY's keygen to create a .ppk file and try connecting with that one?

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be a bit late for you. I've had the same issue as you with my Vagrant file identical to your's and I've resolved it by removing the "aws.session_token = " line.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a simpler solution. I Capitalized "US" in the region name - it was case sensitive - doh !